# How to convert OrderedDict to a list of values only, in Python?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have an `OrderedDict` object and I want to make a list with just the values while keeping the same order they have in the dictionary. Is there an out of the box method to do this? My `OrderedDict` object looks something like this:

```
OrderedDict(
        [
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                    "angle": 74.628235,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            ),
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980),
                    "angle": 8.054147,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            )
        ]
    )
```

My expected output would be something like:

```py
[[datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),74.628235,[15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]],
[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980),8.054147,[15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### FOR ONLY VALUES.

```py
import datetime
OrderedDict = [
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                    "angle": 74.628235,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            ),
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980),
                    "angle": 8.054147,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            )
        ]
    

lst = [list(a[1].values()) for a in OrderedDict]
    

print(lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[[datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913), 74.628235, [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]],
[datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980), 8.054147, [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]]]
```

#### FOR DICTIONARY.

```py
import datetime
OrderedDict = [
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913),
                    "angle": 74.628235,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            ),
            (
                datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                {
                    "time": datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980),
                    "angle": 8.054147,
                    "sizes": [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0],
                },
            )
        ]
    

lst = [a[1] for a in OrderedDict]
    

print(lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[{'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 11, 7, 43, 0, 90913), 'angle': 74.628235, 'sizes': [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]},
 {'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 12, 6, 17, 8, 90980), 'angle': 8.054147, 'sizes': [15.0, 65.0, 10.0, 130.0]}]
```